# Algebras: Homology vs. Resolution as a dg-algebra

Tags: homological-algebra, differential-graded-algebras

My question is what is the relation (if any) between the following two notions.

1. Starting from an augmented algebra $A$ over a field $k$, one way to compute the homology of $A$ is to find a projective resolution of $k$ as an $A$-module.
2. On the other hand, one could also see $A$ as a (let's say positively graded) dg-algebra (concentrated in degree 0), and take a cofibrant replacement of $A$ in this category, using the projective model structure.

Both notions give some notions homotopical information about $A$, and I would be interested in knowing if it is possible to deduce one from the other (presumably, to recover a resolution of $k$ from a cofibrant replacement of $A$), at least in "good" cases.

The reason I ask is because I have two very similar constructions building these objects for suitable algebras, and I am wondering whether one of these constructions can be deduced from the other one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your first description, I guess that what you call "the homology of $A$" is in fact the Hochschild homology of $A$ with constant coefficients, i.e. $HH_*(A;k)$. Please tell me if I got this wrong.

Then yes, it's possible to compute it from a projective resolution of $A$. Suppose that $R \xrightarrow{\sim} A$ is a projective resolution of $A$. Let $\Omega_R$ be the $R$-module of Kähler differentials. Then you can compute the Hochschild homology of $A$ as the André–Quillen homology, i.e. the homology of the complex:
$$k \otimes_{A \otimes A^{op}} (A \otimes_R \Omega_R).$$
The object $\mathbb{L}_{R/A} = A \otimes_R \Omega_R$ is called the cotangent complex of $A$.

Comment: PS: it works for any operad. You can compute the Harrison homology of a commutative algebra, the Chevalley–Eilenberg homology of a Lie algebra, etc, as the analogue of the André–Quillen homology. See e.g. Chapter 12 of the book *Algebraic Operads* (Loday & Vallette) and the references therein.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much!